# stagger effect with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

I have problems trying to make staggered animation.
I've tried this to animate elements from array("box") with delaying every other element by 10ms.But it doesn't work with setTimeout cause "i" value is added after timeout is over.Any advice how to do that?

```
var box=[]
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++){box.push(document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i])}
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {box[i].style.transform="translateX(150px)"},i*10)
    }
```

---

Any help or advice is apprecaited, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer involves using a IIFE to lock in the primitive value of `i` at the time the setTimeout is executed.

```
var box=[]
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++){box.push(document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i])}
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            setTimeout(function () {box[i].style.transform="translateX(150px)"},i*10)
        }(i))  // This copies the value.
    }
```

Comment: this moves all elements at once,I have no idea why

Comment: @Matija have you tried a larger value like `i * 100` to see if it's too fast for what you are doing?  - It had just occurred to me that you used `i` in two loops. Maybe you can change one to `j`.

Comment: yep I tried even a 1000,I logged "i" to console and got numbers from 0 to 49,there's 50 elements in box array

Comment: I added one more timeout next to the first one,that timeout logged "i" with staggered effect as I want

Comment: [It works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/TLeTxCzLmGin9QSaFYI4?p=preview) :/

Answer (score 1):

You can make this code much cleaner like this:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            setTimeout(function () {boxes[i].style.transform="translateX(150px)"},i*200)
        }(i))  // This copies the value.
    }
```

You dont need to push them into an array to access them.

here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w8wbmozs/52/